# Spring Integration Messages sent but not received with activeMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, messaging, spring-integration

I would like to create a simple test when messages are sent to / received from FORWARD queue.
Upon received message a service should be invoked.

Unfortunately, the messages are sent through `Message<?> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(params); forwardGateway.sendPremMessage(message);` but not received.

This is my config:

```
  <!-- SENDER -->

<si:gateway id="forwardGateway" 
    service-interface="com.ucware.ucpo.forward.jms.MessageGateway" 
    default-request-channel="inputChannel"/>

<si:channel id="inputChannel"/>

    <!-- Subscriber to a channel -->
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter 
channel="inputChannel"
connection-factory="connectionFactory" 
destination-name="FORWARD" />


<!-- RECEIVER -->
<int:channel id="jmsInChannel"/>

 <!-- Subscriber to jmsInChannel. Used instead of inboud channel adapter -->
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="messageDrivenAdapter"
    channel="jmsInChannel" destination-name="FORWARD" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    concurrent-consumers="1" auto-startup="true" acknowledge="auto"/>

 // This service should be invoked but it is not 
<si:service-activator id ="activator" 
    input-channel="jmsInChannel"
    ref="messageService" 
    method="process"/>
```

The service is defined as :

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class MessageService   {

public void process(Message<?> message )
```

}
and the gateway as :

```
public interface MessageGateway  {

@Gateway 
public void sendPremMessage(Message<?> message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration works perfectly fine for me; I suggest you turn on TRACE level logging to see the message flow on both sides. (TRACE gives details of the message listener container activity on the receiving side).

If you are using in-memory ActiveMQ you need to be careful about the timing - don't send a message until the container has started. Alternatively be sure to use a `CachingConnectionFactory`.

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

That way, the broker will stay running after the send, even if the container hasn't started yet.